# How to compile TypeScript to JavaScript with jQuery, without any additional libraries or frameworks (NPM, etc.)

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript, tsc

I have an extremely simple single-page dashboard that does things like grab the weather, the subway alerts, etc. and I refresh it locally on my machine. It looked like:

```
project/
  index.html
  jquery-3.3.1.min.js
  script.js
```

And I wanted to convert it to TypeScript. I ported `script.js` to TypeScript, but in order to use jQuery had to download the definition file from [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/master/types/jquery/index.d.ts). I now have:

```
project/
  index.html
  jquery.d.ts
  script.ts
```

The first two lines of my TypeScript file are:

```
/// <reference path ="./jquery.d.ts"/>
import * as $ from "jquery"
```

When I run `tsc *.ts`, it compiles my script successfully, but the first four lines of the resulting/compiled JavaScript file are:

```
"use strict";
exports.__esModule = true;
/// <reference path ="./jquery.d.ts"/>
var $ = require("jquery");
```

And this fails in my browser with:

```
exports.__esModule = true; // Can't find variable: exports
```

I'm a pretty weak front-end developer beyond HTML/JS/jQuery, so I'm not sure where to start - I did some Googling but not much came up.

Comment: If you want to use JQuery via Module you have to use a packer like [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/)  or if you include it locally (inside html) you can use `declare var $: JQuery`

Comment: I don't need to use it as a module - I'd just like to be able to use it... at all. Is there an alternate non-module way to include jQuery without having to introduce another dependency/build step?

Comment: as far as i know is the Type of JQuery included in some versions (or splits) of typescript so you can just include it manually and the declare it in the file with `declare var $: JQuery` or if the type is not defined just use `declare var $: any`

Comment: @RichardFox The `declare var $: any` worked for me - feel free to add that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean so...

use `declare var $: JQuery` if the type is defined

else use `declare vas $: any`

for the case that your editor (f.e. VSCode) supports script var declarations use

```
{ 
 name: "$",
 type: JQuery (or any),
 ofReference: {
  scriptSrc: ["*jquery.js", "*jquery.min.js", "*code.jquery*"] 
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks - copying my comment from above, `declare var $: any` worked for me!